# Generic Noether normalisation

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose that $M$ is a finitely generated module over $A=k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ of Krull dimension $m$ with $k$ an infinite field. Then one version of Noether normalisation says there is an $m$-dimensional $k$-subspace $W$ of the $k$-vector space spanned by $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ such that $M$ is finitely generated over $\operatorname{Sym}(W)$ considered as a subring of $A$.

As is surely well-known, in fact one can show that the set of $m$-dimensional $k$-vector spaces $W$ that work is open in the appropriate Grassmannian. My question is where is there a reference for this fact in the literature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I might be missing something (I often am) but I believe that [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=7ua4WsmpDbMC&pg=PA453&lpg=PA453&dq=noether+normalization+works+generically&source=bl&ots=Rb24oAphIe&sig=fXu2RhCrSf77Dyi0IYHg-mmXMMM&hl=en&ei=ODveSo_2KsbV8AbsiJFn&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false) does it.  Scroll up to page 452, line 3.9.  The book is Effective Methods in Algebraic Geometry by Rossi and Spangher.

Comment: I think that does what I want. Thank you. 

It would be nice to have a reference that isn't the middle of a proof of something else entirely though. If anyone has any other suggestions they are very welcome. 

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has the same question and discovers this page I have just found a more explicit reference for this result: Remark 3.4.4 of *A Singular introduction to commutative algebra* by Greuel and Pfister. [DOI 10.1007/978-3-540-73542-7_3](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-73542-7_3) is a page that links to the appropriate chapter. It is possible that a subscription is required to open it though.

Answer (score 0):

A good reference seems

Adjamagbo, K.; Winiarski, T. **Refined Noether normalization theorem and sharp degree bounds for dominating morphisms**. Comm. Algebra 33 (2005), no. 7, 2387–2393. (Reviewer: David R. Finston)

They state the theorem as follows:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $B=\mathbb K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]=\mathbb K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/I$ be an absolutely integral affine algebra of dimension $r>0$ over an infinite field $\mathbb K$, where $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ and $d$ is the degree of its variety in $\mathbb A^n(\mathbb K)$.
>   If $L$ ifs a generic linear automorphism of $\mathbb K^n$ with components $L_1,\ldots,L_n$, and $A=\mathbb K[L(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ldots,L_r(x_1,\ldots,x_n)]\subseteq B$, then $B$ is a finite module over $A$, the fractions field of $B$ is an extension of the dractions field of $A$ with separable degree $d$, and the cardinality of each fiber of the canonical morphism from $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ to $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is majorated by $d$.

**Edit:** Another good reference might be the red book of varieties and schemes, page 126 at the bottom, this is a remark concerning Proposition 6 in §7.